# C# - String to array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I've a string `"[2030,2031,2032,2033,2034]"` and I want to convert it into an array.

I've already tried this :

```
Array t = teamMembers.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

But it's only taking all the characters to a string.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Remove the `[` and `]`, `.Split` on `','` (and then `Int32.Parse` if you want integers)?

Comment: Use the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Use a comma and square brackets as delimiters.

Comment: Also wanted to note, this looks like a JSON array. If it is, he should probably be using Json.Net for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want strings...

```
var t = teamMembers.Trim('[', ']').Split(',');
```

If you want ints...

```
    var ret = teamMembers.Trim('[', ']').Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use many ways, you can trim first as other suggested, or use the overload of [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131450(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a `char[]` and can remove the empty entries, leaving you with exactly what you want. You can parse it to `int` if you'd like an `int` array.

```
var intArray = teamMembers
                    .Split(new[] { '[', ']', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(int.Parse);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var input = "[2030,2031,2032,2033,2034]";
 var output = input.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string, it will be converted to array.

```
    var teamMembers ="[2030,2031,2032,2033,2034]";

    var t = teamMembers.Trim('[', ']').Split(',');
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hsMrDh

One more way is

```
     var t1 = teamMembers.Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove "[ ]" using below code
     teamMembers.Trim('[', ']');
and spilt it with "," delimiter
      teamMembers.Trim('[', ']').split(',');